# NLog connection string for SQL Server mirrored database

Tags: sql-server, nlog

Setting up an application to use a mirrored database in `SQL Server`. My connection string to the DB looks like this:

```
Data Source=svrDBPrinciple;Failover Partner=svrDBMirror;
```

However, putting the same into the `NLog` connection string, using the same security details to the functional DB connection results in a "Login failed for user" error.

Can one configure NLog to use an automatic failover?

EDIT - config file was asked for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogFile="[a path]\internal_log_file.txt"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogToConsole="true">

  <targets>

    <target xsi:type="Database" name="database" 
    dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=svrDBPrinciple;Failover Partner=svrDBMirror;Initial Catalog=[catalogue];User ID=[id];Password=[pwd];">
        <commandText>
        INSERT INTO [Logging] ([LogDate], [Severity], [Message], [Source], [Exception], [Inner])
                        VALUES( @date,    @severity,  @message,  @source,  @exception,  @inner)
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@date" layout="${date}"/>
      <parameter name="@severity" layout="${level}"/>
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
      <parameter name="@source" layout="${logger} ${callsite}"/>
      <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:format=tostring}"/>
      <parameter name="@inner" layout="${exception:innerFormat=tostring}" />
    </target>

    <target name="file"
    type="File"
    fileName="[a path and filename]_${shortdate}.log"
    layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message} ${exception:format=Message, Type, ShortType, ToString, Method, StackTrace:separator=, }"/>

  </targets>

  <rules>
     <logger name="*" levels="Trace, Debug, Fatal, Error, Warn, Info" writeTo="file" />
     <logger name="*" levels="Trace, Debug, Fatal, Error, Warn, Info" writeTo="database" /> 
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

- The file logging works as expected.
- The connection string works when
  used outside NLog.
- The database logging works when used on a single,
  non-mirrored database

So I'm forced to conclude that NLog must interact differently with mirrored databases than standard SQL Server connection strings?

Comment: please check https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target link.

Comment: also you can find answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188478/how-do-i-configure-nlog-to-write-to-a-database

Comment: If the linked questions doesn't answer your question, then please post the nlog.config

Comment: @Julian thanks - have done so. I'm sure it's to do with the failover, as explained in the question. The config works fine using file logging or when logging to a single, non-mirrored DB.

Comment: @UmutCatal Thanks - have posted the log file

Comment: You may need to set the provider in the db target as per @UmutCatal's link. The System.Data.SqlClient provider supports a failover partner however the default might not support it.

Comment: @GDavison Sorry, that's in there - I deleted it by accident while I was removing passwords and stuff. Have edited. Am I using the wrong provider string?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to both the principal and mirror SQL Servers with the same user account and password. It could be when the database is failed over, the user account has a different SID which means the SQL user account doesn't map to the database user account. You could use [sp_change_users_login](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174378.aspx) to fix the user account on the mirror server, or alternately recreate the user account on the mirror with the same SID as the user on the principal.