# Target database schema could not be retrieved - Visual Studio Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

I am new to programming in **Visual Studio** C#. I have been trying to create a table using a **Stored Procedure**. When I try to update the table, I get an error.

The Stored Procedure script is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
[Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Error] VARCHAR(30) NULL
)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertLog]
(
@error varchar(30)
)

AS

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
(
[Error]
)
VALUES
(
@error
)

GO
```

My connection string is as follows:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Persist Security Info=true;Integrated Security=True;"
```

The error I get when updating the table is as follows:

[image]

I am using the LocalDB and I have no login credentials. Kindly help me with the error.

**Note:** I also went through other StackOverflow questions and none helped.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer to the following steps to execute the stored procedure.

First, you can create table like the following picture. Here I want to mention that you

need to use automatic increment if you want to use the stored procedure you provided.

Also, you can not create stored procedure here.

[image]

Second, click database->choose Programmability->choose stored procedures-> right click Add new procedure like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertLog]
(
@error varchar(30)
)

AS

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Newtable]
(
[Error]
)
VALUES
(
@error
)
```

[image]

Finally, you can use the following code to call stored procedure in c#.

```
        string connectionstring = @"Connectionstring";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("InsertLog",connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@error", textBox1.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
```

Comment: I am using NLog to log error messages to the DB. So, in my case, I don't need to use the `AddWithValue` method right? **NLog** has `logger.Error()` method. How would I use this within this context?

Comment: If you want to know how to use NLog to log the error to the database, you could see [How do I configure NLog to write to a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188478/how-do-i-configure-nlog-to-write-to-a-database).

Answer (score 0):

How have you mentioned your connection string? COuld you please add that as well

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0a091760-2842-4d0b-be99-04c96de3e0c2/cant-connect-to-local-database-file-mdf-using-sql-server-authentication?forum=sqlgetstarted
Please try the above link- it will help you to setup what you are looking. Please let me know if it doesnt